# How to Serialize a ListItem Stored in Session

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, serialization, listitem

I have this code which works fine on my local server:

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
    string[] questions = new string[20];
    string[] answers = new string[20];
    for (int i = 0; i < lstQuestions.Items.Count; ++i)
    {
        questions[i] = lstQuestions.Items[i].Text;
        answers[i] = lstQuestions.Items[i].Value;
    }
    Session["questions"] = questions;
    Session["answers"] = answers;
    if (Session["qalist"] == null)
    {
        List<ListItem> qalist = lstQuestions.Items.Cast<ListItem>().ToList();
        Session["qalist"] = qalist;
    }
    else
    {
        List<ListItem> qalist = (List<ListItem>)Session["qalist"];
        lstQuestions.DataSource = qalist;
    }
}

else
{
    if (Session["questions"] != null && Session["answers"] != null && Session["qalist"] != null)
    {
        List<ListItem> qalist = (List<ListItem>)Session["qalist"];
        foreach (ListItem item in qalist)
        {
            lstQuestions.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.Text, item.Value.ToString()));
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I go to the web server, I get the error "System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem, not marked as serializable". I've looked into how I can make this serializable, or even how to convert "qalist" to a value that is in fact serializable, and then save that value to a session. However, my efforts were to no avail. Would serializing be the best route? Finding a different way to store this data? Or something else?

Comment: It's simple. "Don't _do_ that". A `ListItem` is not serializable so you have to store enough data in Session to create a `ListItem` when you need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem` is not serializable, as you have observed. Thus you can't store it in session.

I'm a little confused why you're saving the two data properties of the `ListItem` - `questions` and `answers` - separately into Session, and also the `ListItem` itself. It looks to me that, having `questions` and `answers`, you have all you need to reconstruct a `ListItem`.

But if you want to save your question and answer together as a pair, you could use a `List<T>` of `System.Tuple<string, string>`, which is serializable, or even `System.Web.UI.Pair`, which is also serializable.

You could also write your own (very simple) class, and mark it as serializable:

```
[Serializable]
public class QuestionAndAnswer
{
    public string Question { get; set;}
    public string Answer { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The text from `Session["questions"]`, `Session["answers"]` and `Session["qalist"]` all populate different items and serve for more than one purpose. It's hard to explain without showing a bunch of unnecessary code, so I won't go into their exact functions. Thank you for the answer, I will give it a try.

Comment: Figured I'd answer and say that I took your advice and it did in fact work. If anyone needs a comparison for future reference, here's what I ended with:
Before going into the `for` loop- `List<Tuple<string, string>> qatuple = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();` In the `for` loop - `qatuple.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(questions[i], answers[i]));` After the `for` loop- `Session["qatuple"] = qatuple; qatuple = (List<Tuple<string, string>>)Session["qatuple"]; lstQuestions.DataSource = qatuple;`

Answer (score 1):

You can try use JSON.Net (Newtonsoft) to do the serialization and deserialization.

To serialize

```
Session["qalist"] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(lstQuestions);
```

To deserialize (T is the type of lstQuestions)

```
lstQuestions = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(Session["qalist"]);
```

I hope it help